# Finding multiple modes of a vector using maps c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I am trying to write a function that takes a vector and then counts the frequency of each element in the vector using a map. The ones with the highest frequency get pushed into a new vector, and then I am trying to return the vector to be output in my main function.

```
vector<double> mode(vector<double> v)
{
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    vector<double> modes;
    map<int,double> frequencyCount;
    for(size_t i; i<v.size(); i++)
        frequencyCount[v[i]]++;
    double current_max = 0;
    for (auto iter = frequencyCount.cbegin(); iter != frequencyCount.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter ->second > current_max)
        {
        modes.push_back(iter->first);
        current_max = iter->second;
        }
    }
    if (current_max == 1)
    {
        cout << "No mode exists." << endl;
    }
    else
        return modes;
}
```

I then call it in main:

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> m = mode(v);
    cout << "Mode:    ";
    for (size_t i; i<m.size(); i++)
        cout << m[i];
}
```

no errors, but nothing is output... any advice?

Comment: In `main` where is `v` defined and populated?

Comment: You have the type for your map reversed. You also need to initialize it. It should be `std::map<double, int> frequencyCount(v.size(), 0);`

Comment: As @KurtStutsman points out the types in the `std::map` are reversed (i.e., it should be `std::map<double, int>`) but floating-point is imprecise and using `double` as a key may not behave exactly the way you're expecting.

Comment: The `mode` function needs to **always** return the appropriate type. As written, it does not always return a result.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: It's not merely imprecise: it fails to provide the strict weak ordering required by `map`--if you end up trying to use a NaN as a key, expect it to fail (probably fairly spectacularly).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Great point! I wasn't thinking about `NaN` when I made that comment.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the overall improvement tips for the functionality! I have implemented things and it seems to be working well. Now for automated tests!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(size_t i; i<v.size(); i++)
```

You forgot to initialize `i` to 0. The index variable is uninitialized. Undefined behavior.

Additionally, the overall algorithm could be improved in several ways, but that's not what was asked, here.

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much! Helps to have a second eye look over things huh? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after making a few adjustments, I also realized my logic was incorrect. The function was calling `modes.push_back(iter->first)` before `current_max` was done iterating through the entire map. So I changed my loop to find the max frequency, and then iterated through the map again printing out the `first` from each pair where `second` matched the `current max`. Here is the working code, along with the main function. Any more advice to make this more efficient?

```
vector<double> mode(vector<double> v)
{
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    vector<double> modes;
    map<double, int> frequencyCount;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<v.size(); i++)
        frequencyCount[v[i]]++;
    double current_max = 0;
    for (auto iter = frequencyCount.cbegin(); iter != frequencyCount.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter -> second > current_max)
        {
            current_max = iter->second;
        }
    }
    for (auto it = frequencyCount.cbegin(); it != frequencyCount.cend(); ++it)
    {
        if (it -> second == current_max)
            modes.push_back(it->first);
    }
    return modes;
}
```

and main:

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> v = input();
    vector<double> m = mode(v);

    cout << "Mode:    ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i<(m.size()-1); i++)
        cout << m[i] << ", ";
    cout << m[m.size()-1];
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```